# What happened to the Pick And Place Manager in groovy?

Tags: ros, ros-groovy, pick-and-place

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In my application, I've been using the `PickAndPlaceManager` from the `pr2_pick_and_place_demos` package. At the moment, I'm trying to convert our software to Groovy, but the `PickAndPlaceManager` is gone. Some questions:

- What are the reasons for removing it? Will it come back?
- How hard would it be to upgrade it to Groovy? What would have to be done?
- Is there an alternative? I.e., what's the preferred way to pick up and place objects using the PR2 on Groovy?

Thanks!
Martin

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/65044/what-happened-to-the-pick-and-place-manager-in-groovy?/) by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11816 on 2013-06-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Pick and place manager has been updated and added back to branch groovy-devel in https://github.com/ros-interactive-manipulation/pr2_object_manipulation .  Sorry it took so long!  Hopefully you had good luck with MoveIt! in the meantime. :)

The pick and place manager will definitely not be in Hydro, in any event--arm navigation and all of that has been deprecated.  Switch now if you can!

---

Originally posted by [hsiao](https://answers.ros.org/users/142/hsiao/) with karma: 741 on 2013-08-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2013-08-18**:
Well, I don't think I can switch to MoveIt yet; it doesn't yet seem to provide all the features that arm_navigation, object_manipulation etc. did. Thanks anyway (also to Dan Lazewasky), I'll give arm_navigation on groovy another try.

**Comment by [hsiao](https://answers.ros.org/users/142/hsiao/) on 2013-08-18**:
BTW, make sure you do sudo apt-get remove ros-groovy-geometric-shapes before trying to install.  There's a geometric_shapes dry package in arm_navigation that conflicts with the wet version used by MoveIt! so if you've installed MoveIt! on your computer, you'll have to uninstall it before arm_navigation will compile.

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2013-08-18**:
Thanks for the hint! Do you have any plans on solving the geometric-shapes issue?

**Comment by [hsiao](https://answers.ros.org/users/142/hsiao/) on 2013-08-19**:
No plans, alas.  It's likely you'll just have to pick one or the other forever.  Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just didn't port it forward because we were planning to switch to MoveIt! imminently.  The switch still hasn't happened, though, so it should be brought back.  It wouldn't be hard to upgrade--just some of the messages have changed somewhat.  If you have time to get to it now I'd be happy to merge a pull request with it.  Otherwise I'll try to get to it eventually-soonish.

---

Originally posted by [hsiao](https://answers.ros.org/users/142/hsiao/) with karma: 741 on 2013-06-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1